# SSRS change hide border text when column empty

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have 4 columns `id, lname, fname, age`.

I have several records then I can see all of them and border around.

If I have records with id, lname, fname and say null or nothing in age column then I like to hide left and right border in age column.

Is it possible to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you should be able to use an Expression to set the border properties for cells in your Age column. It might be easier for people to answer your question if you can explain more clearly what you're trying to do and why, or perhaps even provide screenshots to illustrate.

Comment: I just found the way to do it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: How do I give you credit?

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer, if you'd like to accept it and upvote, I'll get rep for that. Glad you got the problem solved! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you should be able to use an Expression to set the border properties for cells in your Age column. It might be easier for people to answer your question if you can explain more clearly what you're trying to do and why, or perhaps even provide screenshots to illustrate.

Comment: I'm using expression on text box to hide the border. That's it.

Comment: Not sure why I'm no longer accepting questions from my account.